# Why is this whole mesh being reconfigured when it is transformed with G, R, or S?

Tags: modeling, mesh, transforms

This mesh may have artifacts that I haven't tracked down, it's given me trouble and there has been a lot of fiddling. Maybe that is why suddenly, after a lot of manipulation, in edit mode if the whole thing is chosen and moved, rotated, or scaled, a bunch of faces collapse and the entire mesh changes a lot.

[image: mesh before] [image: mesh after]

Why is this happening and what can I do about it?

Comment: what kind of modifiers do you have on the object?

Comment: Do you have automerge enabled?

Comment: @Denis Yes. I just moved the whole thing though, and i've done that plenty of other times with automerge on.

Comment: @zeffii no modifiers.

Comment: I guess if you scaled the mesh to very small size and then moved the vertices in edit mode it collapse the vertices

Comment: @Denis Yep, turning it off made it stop. I'd like to use it later though. I guess i'll lower the merge distance and leave it off until i need it.